# rsync can not delete .git/objects directory files

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, git, rsync

I am running the command:

```
rsync -ab --delete-delay /media/blueray/WDRed /media/blueray/UltrastarDaily
```

Just to be clear, it delete destination file (`--delete-delay`) if the file is removed from the source.

And it is yielding the following output (part of the output):

```
rsync: open "/media/blueray/UltrastarDaily/WDRed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/.git/objects/aa/0f7214d22e712099a0d3509c72308146893e57" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/media/blueray/UltrastarDaily/WDRed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/.git/objects/ab/b150515f74a76f331ee275ef2768a91115b320" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/media/blueray/UltrastarDaily/WDRed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/.git/objects/ab/baad7a7409b4d0bbdcef7c9890bb1f5d46a823" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/media/blueray/UltrastarDaily/WDRed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/.git/objects/b3/8ed79ad4f5956cfa129fe1df0e9ec00c746672" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/media/blueray/UltrastarDaily/WDRed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/.git/objects/b5/8f91ac5efdc0e53a83eba11a0e632a4dea73ec" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/media/blueray/UltrastarDaily/WDRed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/.git/objects/b5/abcc64e88d77813bdc47005f9accb72746326a" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/media/blueray/UltrastarDaily/WDRed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/.git/objects/b5/f6af97229a1bd644fc58a9c54c136f880fa530" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/media/blueray/UltrastarDaily/WDRed/_Working/_NotesFiltered/.git/objects/b6/400def87b4544f9ef2b246be8170e5b03a686c" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

I checked the file permission. It is showing:

```
% ls -lg
.r--r--r--  128 blueray blueray  7 Feb  4:36 0f7214d22e712099a0d3509c72308146893e57
.r--r--r--  100 blueray blueray 18 Dec  2020 4c43240f470ae0d19198beab1ceee59b8ba400
.r--r--r--  236 blueray blueray 18 Dec  2020 9b80263fab88c02738a91bbe15763801b415fd
.r--r--r--  626 blueray blueray 18 Dec  2020 47ffc8062e197dc9c76f199032a2fe5f0c40a8
.r--r--r-- 1.1M blueray blueray  5 Apr 23:13 217fc19b7887fe3ba24f828aa2880235e16158
.r--r--r-- 2.4k blueray blueray 22 May 23:47 677b3290ebd20ff33b0496f76e1e71e6566e07
.r--r--r--  25k blueray blueray 18 Dec  2020 7682be228dd8c0e303d9bb51c2388ab122afe3
.r--r--r--  350 blueray blueray  7 Feb  4:36 a33ca86640f0614b80bbb27bdcf7941c5c04f9
.r--r--r-- 122k blueray blueray 22 May 23:47 a70c7a10521b3c0e320385f1528e8975bb1b16
.r--r--r--  209 blueray blueray 18 Dec  2020 a86944d79a34ef90d3d9f4db20a9622a920695
.r--r--r-- 1.2k blueray blueray 18 Dec  2020 b93b3e139d6362c6120193a49ee635ceeeba85
.r--r--r-- 1.3k blueray blueray 18 Dec  2020 c9b598d13d373fe0d789d9f6211e9bbb244a8e
.r--r--r--  385 blueray blueray 18 Dec  2020 cdda3fa1a3f0bbfda08072c20eba28bec1dcf8
.r--r--r--  137 blueray blueray 18 Dec  2020 d11be88a036d4b42fb9826db1f74b2ff818577
.r--r--r-- 1.1M blueray blueray 18 Dec  2020 fae0391be02b5054ad949e684ebe8bcb151ac0
```

If I give write permission to these git objects then the rsync command works.

My problem is, I have many git repos in backup directory. I can not go to each directory and change permission after every commit.

If I could give write permission to `rsync` files for git objects then it would be better. Actually any workaround that does not involve going to each directory and change permission after every commit will be better.

Comment: Is `rsync` being run on demand from your account or is this part of a scheduled job?

Comment: rsync is being run on demand from my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be ok with a script that first changes the permissions.
It could work on specific directories or on all `.git/objects` in a (sub)set of directories.

Taking as an example the command line you posted in the question

```
rsync -ab --delete-delay /media/blueray/WDRed /media/blueray/UltrastarDaily
```

and naming `rsync_my.sh` script below,

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="${@:$#}"   # last parameter
SOURCE="${@:(-2):1}"   # second to last parameter
TARGET2="${TARGET}/$(basename ${SOURCE})/_Working/_NotesFiltered/
for d in $(find ${TARGET2} -type d -name .git) ; do 
    chmod -R +w $d/objects
    for d2 in $(find ${d} -type d) ; do
        chmod +x $d2
    done
done
rsync "$@"
```

you would execute

```
$ chmod +x rsync_my.sh
$ ./rsync_my.sh -ab --delete-delay /media/blueray/WDRed /media/blueray/UltrastarDaily
```

The first command is needed only once. `SOURCE` would be `/media/blueray/WDRed` and `TARGET` would be `/media/blueray/UltrastarDaily`.
Please test it and post feedback.
To test, you could

1. Put together a dummy directory/file structure with some 10 files that replicates the essential structure of your target dir, and execute the script.
2. With `rsync`, use option `--dry-run` to only see what would be done, and create a log file that you can later inspect with `--log-file=mylog.log`.

Parameter expansion/extraction may need fine tuning.

**Related**:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41382232/git-objects-directory-contents-make-git-set-the-write-permission-instead-of
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab/6448326

Comment: @blueray - I have heavily edited the answer, addressing your questions.
You are right about permissions, I mixed up. Plus, directories need `+x` permissions, that is why I added the nested `for` loop.

Comment: what is TARGET2 doing?

Comment: @blueray - Putting together `/media/blueray/UltrastarDaily/WDRed/_Working/_NotesFiltered`. You may need to adjust that. You could insert a command like `echo ${TARGET2}` to further check how it works. It will be much more instructive and expeditive.

Comment: thank you very much. I only had to use the first loop though. not sure why you are using the second loop.

Comment: @blueray - As mentioned, I expected you would need `+x` for directories to access them. But if you found it is not needed (and I would later tinker a bit, whether that is related specifically to `rsync` or else), that's fine. I'm glad it worked.